# Keep terminal window on top

Tags: raspbian, python, boot, lxterminal

I have 2 scripts running once desktop loads both running a python script call them A &  B

script B looks for keypress so has to remain on top always.

How can I boot both A &  B but make sure B is always on top

This is a desktop setup but headless

Comment: What do you mean by "to remain on top"?

Comment: Yes I need to make sure B is always on top ready to type into

Comment: @techraf I think he means that he wants the program to launch on boot and cover the top half of the screen on boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way using [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl)

So changed my terminal title using

`-t title-name`

Then added

`wmctrl -a title-name`

To my .sh script